# C# cloned MouseHover/MouseLeave applies to original control & not current

Tags: c#, mouseover, mouseleave, mousehover

I have a form that I **add controls in a panel**

> one of them is a PictureBox holds a MouseHover/MouseLeave event like
>   this

```
void PropAction_pBoxMouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PropAction_pBox.ImageLocation = @"PicButtons\PropertiesBtn2.png";
}
void PropAction_pBoxMouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PropAction_pBox.ImageLocation = @"PicButtons\PropertiesBtn2White.png";
}
```

In the add button I have this code

> **create** a **new** button **based** on the  newPropAction ***(original)*** and add 
>   it in a list *
>
> > " newPropAction_pBox represents the new PictureBox & PropAction_pBox represents the original PictureBox "*

```
        PictureBox newPropAction_pBox = new PictureBox();
        newPropAction_pBox.Image = PropAction_pBox.Image;
        newPropAction_pBox.Click += PropAction_pBoxClick;
        newPropAction_pBox.MouseHover += PropAction_pBoxMouseHover;
        newPropAction_pBox.MouseLeave += PropAction_pBoxMouseLeave;
        this.Controls.Add(newPropAction_pBox);// add to controls
        ActionPictures.Add(newPropAction_pBox); //Add to btn to list
```

But the **final effect** is this *(pictures below)*

> Mouse not on pictureBox yet : http://prnt.sc/axt8b9
>
> Mouse on the new PictureBox : http://prnt.sc/axt9ul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code as follows

```
void PropAction_pBoxMouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pictureBox = (PictureBox)sender;
    pictureBox.ImageLocation = @"PicButtons\PropertiesBtn2.png";
}

void PropAction_pBoxMouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pictureBox = (PictureBox)sender;
    pictureBox.ImageLocation = @"PicButtons\PropertiesBtn2White.png";
}
```

Object `sender` is source of the event. Parameter `sender` refers to the instance that raises the event.
Thus the event handler receives information, what kind of object is the source of this event.

Comment: WOW it worked but please explain to me at the name of the original `PictureBox is PropAction_pBox` how does the `var pictureBox.ImageLocation` works like `PropAction_pBox.ImageLocation`

Comment: @ehem - See update. So hard to write in English. So easy to write code.

Comment: so the `(PictureBox)sender` returns  to the `object sender` , in simple words . Anyway I understood how it works , have a nice day